# Powershell copy only selected files with folder structure

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a folder hierarchy with a lot of files.
I need to copy all folders and only selected files. For this purposes I write script:

```
$path = "D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "system.serviceModel.client.config" }
$Destination = "D:\test\"
Copy-Item $files -Destination $Destination -recurse
```

When I execute variable $files, it returns correct path:

[image]

But when I execute Copy-Item it returns not full path:

[image]

Perhaps my approach is wrong. If so, how to copy entire folder structure, and only selected files (in this case system.serviceModel.client.config file)?

UPD1 Ok, I've found, how to copy only folders:

```
$path = "D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181\"
$Destination = "D:\test\"
Copy-Item $path $Destination -Filter {PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Force
```

But how to copy only selected files, preserving their location? What needs to be in $Destination variable?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "system.serviceModel.client.config" } | % { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the whole folder structure AND files with a certain name, below code should do what you want:

```
$Source      = 'D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181'
$Destination = 'D:\test'
$FileToCopy  = 'system.serviceModel.client.config'

# loop through the source folder recursively and return both files and folders
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        # if it's a folder, create the new path from the FullName property
        $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($Source.Length)
        $copyFile = $false
    }
    else {
        # if it's a file, create the new path from the DirectoryName property
        $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($Source.Length)
        # should we copy this file? ($true or $false)
        $copyFile = ($_.Name -like "*$FileToCopy*")
    }
    # create the target folder if this does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    if ($copyFile) {
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFolder -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code would keep the directory structure the same too

```
$path = "D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181\"
$Destination = "D:\test\"
$fileName = "system.serviceModel.client.config"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |  ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Name -like $fileName) {
        $dest = "$Destination$(($_.FullName).Replace($path,''))"
        $null = New-Item $dest -Force
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, first variant doesn't copied any files at all, and second - only one copy of file system.serviceModel.client.config was copied in root of D:\test, without any folder structure

Comment: @VasiliyVegas based on your comments I edited my answer. Hopefully, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$path = 'D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181\'
$Destination = 'D:\test\'

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File | where Name -like "*system.serviceModel.client.config*" | %{

$Dir=$_.DirectoryName.Replace($path, $Destination)
$NewPAthFile=$_.FullName.Replace($path, $Destination)

#create dir if not exists
New-Item -Path $Dir -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#copy file in new dir
Copy-Item $_.FullName $NewPAthFile 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes I'd suggest the following:

```powershell
$path = "D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "system.serviceModel.client.config" }
$Destination = "D:\test\"
$files | % { $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -recurse }
```

You can even put the whole copy on one line:

```powershell
$path = "D:\Drop\SOA-ConfigurationManagement - Test\181"
$Destination = "D:\test\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "system.serviceModel.client.config" } | % { $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -recurse }
```

Copy-Item can find the path from the stream of input objects but it doesn't seem to be able to take a collection of `System.IO.FileInfo` objects as an argument to `Path`.